# Where is the sound menu on Rhythmbox. r

Tags: sound, rhythmbox

Where do you click to open it? There is no sound.We just got Ubuntu yesterday and I know literally NOTHING about where to find things...I'm accustomed to Windows Media Player.

And is it worth collecting music on Rhythmbox? Is it being phased out as Windows XP was?

Comment: Welcome to Ask ubuntu! It is great that you have come to us for help! But it seems that your question is not clear. What do you mean by sound menu? Actually why are searching for the sound menu? What do you want to do in the sound menu?

Answer (score 0):

In rhythmbox, sound icon is in top right corner. Click on that icon, now you can be able to adjust the volume.

[image]